# Shared element transition with more than one id

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to create a Shared element transition between two activities, on the first activity, lets call it activity A. I have two views with the same ID. And now you ask: *But how can you create a activity with two views with same id's?* Allow me to explain.

I have a custom card view where I have multiple instances of it on my activity A, let's call them *CV1* and *CV2*. Both *CV1* and *CV2* have a title which is a TextView, and since they are the same custom view, both titles share the same id.

What I'm trying to to: When the user clicks on CV1, I want to animate the CV1 title to be the Activity B title, and when the user clicks on CV2 I want to animate CV2 title to be Activity B title, and so on...

What is happening: When I click on the CV2, CV3 or CV4..., the title that gets animated is always the CV1 title. And yes the CV1 is the first element on my screen, which makes sense why is always the CV1 title who gets the animation.

This is how I get the view to animate:

```java
private Bundle createSharedAnim() {
        return ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                new Pair<>(findViewById(R.id.tv_filled_custom_card_value), VIEW_NAME_VALUE)).toBundle();
    }
```

The `R.id.tv_filled_custom_card_value` is the CV title id.

How can I get the right title to get animated?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just managed to make it work, and it was super easy...

Since I'm using onClickListener to capture the click, I alread have the clicked View on my callback.

So my new code is:

```java
private Bundle createSharedAnim(View view) {
        return ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                new Pair<>(view.findViewById(R.id.tv_filled_custom_card_value), VIEW_NAME_VALUE)).toBundle();
    }
```

Now I receive the clicked view as param and than I call `findViewById` on that view.